# Quick question, Intersection and Spans

Tags: linear-algebra

Given: $K ,T$ are subsets of Linear space $V$.

If $K \cap T = \varnothing$

Is it necessary true that the sum $Sp(K) + Sp(T)$ is a direct sum?

Well, I tried giving $K =\{(1,0),(0,0)\}$ ,$T = \{(2,0),(0,0)\}$ But

$ \{(1,0),(0,0)\} \cap \{(2,0),(0,0)\}  \ne \varnothing $ because it equals to $\{(0,0)\}$

What I'm planning to 'achieve' is
$Sp(K) \cap Sp(T) \ne {0}$ while $K \cap T = \varnothing$ and then I can say that Sp(K) + Sp(T) isn't necessary a direct sum because it's intesection isn't {0} while 'maintaining' $K \cap T = \varnothing$

Answer (score 2):

Just let $K=\{(1,0)\}$ and $T=\{(2,0)\}$ instead.

Comment: Thanks Jasper! Feeling stupid today :(